# How to replace the Apache AliasMatch function in Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx

I want to migrate an Apache server to Nginx.

I'm new with Nginx. I got almost everything I want to do but I am stuck with a problem.

I must transfer these Apache lines of code to Nginx:

```
AliasMatch /*\.(p|P)(h|H)(p|P) /var/www/htdocs/index.php
AliasMatch /*\.(a|A)(s|S)(p|P) /var/www/htdocs/index.php
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.
Manuelix

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Nginx alias like so:

```
location ~ /*\.(p|P)(h|H)(p|P) {
    alias /var/www/htdocs/index.php;
}

location ~ /*\.(a|A)(s|S)(p|P) {
    alias /var/www/htdocs/index.php;
}
```

Comment: Hello Ian, can you please take a look here? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395382/combining-certbot-with-an-nginx-server-block-maker